# Can't update HTML of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create an element dynamically:

```
$('.dataTables_paginate li.previous').after( '<li class="info" />' );
```

and then I'm trying to update its HTML:

```
console.log(pre); // <b>1 - 20</b> of <b>1,447 entries</b>
if ($('.dataTables_paginate li.info')) {
    console.log('element exists'); // element exists
    $('.dataTables_paginate li.info').html(pre);
}
```

The logs print everything correctly but I'm not sure why the element's html doesn't change, it stays empty (`<li class="info"></li>`). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your code works fine https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/0vwe44vx/

Comment: what's the content of `pre`? Is it `showing xx of xx`?

Comment: @A.Lau Updated the description

Comment: maybe caching issue? Have you tried running your updated code in incognito mode?

Comment: I don't know why the downvote .. but anyway .. this piece of code has no problem https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/0vwe44vx/1/ .. may be your problem anywhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check that an element exists you must put it this way

```
if($(elem).length){
  //some code
}
```

*Your code works however you can put it this way*

```js
$(function(){
  var pre = "<b>1 - 20</b> of <b>1,447 entries</b>";
  var $info = $("<li>").html(pre);
  $('.dataTables_paginate li.previous').after( $info );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dataTables_paginate">
  <li class="previous"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @2by2 I also notice it

Comment: This is insert everytime, thats why I used HTML

Answer (score 0):

Jquery documentation states that .html(string s), takes a *string* as the parameter.

Either set your variable to the string tag, like this:

```
var pre = "<some html tag>"
```

Or pass the string tag in as the parameter:

```
.html("<pre>")
```